# Finite field and field elements

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $K = \mathbb{Q}(a_1,a_2,...a_n)$ such that $a_i^2 \in \mathbb{Q}$.

If we take one element from $K$, say $x$, can we somehow express that element using elements $a_1,...a_n$?

Comment: Well, how have you had that field defined?

Comment: It seems that your question is automatically true.

Answer (score 1):

It is true in general that if $K:F$ is a field extension and $a_1, \ldots, a_n\in K$ are algebraic over $F$ then $F[a_1, \ldots, a_n]$ (the smallest ring which contains $F$ and the $a_i$'s) is actually a field.

This follows inductively once we establish this for $n=1$.

So let $a\in K$ be algebraic over $F$. We will show that $F[a]$ is a field.

Define function $f:F[x]\to F[a]$ as $f(p(x))=p(a)$.

Then $f$ is a ring homomorphism whose kernel is the ideal generated by the minimal polynomial of $a$ over $F$.
Since the minimal polynomial is irreducible, the ideal generated by it is a prime ideal. But since $F[x]$ is a PID, this ideal is maximal, and consequently $F[x]/\ker f\cong F[a]$ is a field.

We usually write this as $F(a)$ rather than $F[a]$.

Thus each element of $F(a)$ is just $p(a)$ for some polynomial $p(x)\in F[x]$.

> Similarly, each element in $F(a_1, \ldots, a_n)$ looks like $p(a_1, \ldots, a_n)$ for some $p(x_1, \ldots, x_n)\in F[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$.

Comment: Ok, so $x = \alpha_1a_1 + \alpha_2 a_2 + ... + \alpha_n a_n + \beta_1 a_1a_2 + \beta_2 a_1a_3 + ...... + \gamma_1 a_1a_2a_3+ .... + \lambda a_1a_2...a_n$?

Comment: the exponent of an $a_i$ can be larger than $1$. You seem to be thinking that each exponent is either $0$ or $1$.

Comment: But $a_i^2 \in \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: In your particular example yes. I was thinking in the context of my answer.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about my example. I get that in general it is not 0 or 1. Ok, thank You. :)